# How to write a memcpy function full MISRA:2012 compatible?

Tags: c, void-pointers, misra, qualifiers

I wrote this `memcpy` function, but I still need to disable rules 11.5 and 11.8. Is there a solution to be full MISRA:2012 compatible?

```
#pragma cstat_suppress="MISRAC2012-Rule-21.6" // Uses of stdio.h were found.
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

extern int main(void);

static int_least8_t _memcpy(void *dst, const void *src, const size_t length)
{
    #pragma cstat_disable="MISRAC2012-Rule-11.5" // A conversion from a pointer to void into a pointer to object was found.
    int_least8_t* destination = (int_least8_t*)dst;
    #pragma cstat_disable="MISRAC2012-Rule-11.8" // A cast that removes a const or volatile qualification was found.
    const int_least8_t* source = (int_least8_t*)src;
    #pragma cstat_restore="MISRAC2012-Rule-11.5","MISRAC2012-Rule-11.8"

    for (size_t i = 0; i < (length / sizeof(int_least8_t)); i++)
    {
        destination[i] = source[i];
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    int32_t src[32];
    int32_t dst[32];

    (void)memset(src, 0xff, sizeof(src));

    (void)_memcpy(dst, src, 128);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < (sizeof(src) / sizeof(src[0])); i++)
    {
        (void)printf("%d <=> %d\n", src[i], dst[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I am using IAR as a compiler and C-STAT for static analysis.

Comment: Can you explain to us rules 11.5 and 11.8, so we don't have to go and look them up? You'll get more assistance if you formulate this as a programming question you see.

Comment: @Joe done, but there is something interesting in the last MISRA amendement: https://www.misra.org.uk/LinkClick.aspx?fileticket=V2wsZxtVGkE%3D&tabid=57. It seems memcpy is a special case

Comment: @nowox That amendment is not particularly interesting, someone's been digging too deep in the strict aliasing rule again. `memcpy` has no type safety and that's just how it is. In addition, `memcpy` itself plays a part in determining the effective type of an object. Yet another rule with a poor rationale. Anyway, your code is not the standard library `memcpy` anyhow, so the rule does not apply.

Comment: Names starting with underscore are reserved for the implementation. They **may not** be used by application code. As a sidenote: why don't youi use your standard library's `memcpy` which is most likely highly optimised but some homebrew, most slowly version?

Comment: Why does your `_memcpy` return 0?  That will be a surprise for anyone expecting it to work like the standard `memcpy()`.  And there's absolutely no need to cast away the `const` like that: `const int_least8_t* source = (const int_least8_t*)src;` should be fine.

Comment: Amendment 1 gives you some extra rules to address (some of) the problems with memcpy() - but writing your own MYmemcpy() is not the answer!

Comment: Rule 21.6 does not ban the use of stdio.h - just the I/O functions therein.  It is perfectly legitimate to `#include <stdio.h>` to access NULL, EOF, size_t etc

Comment: @Andrew NULL and size_t are defined in `stddef.h`. And I can't really see a use for EOF if you aren't using the stdio I/O functions. So there should never be a reason to include `stdio.h` in a MISRA-C compliant program.

Comment: I agree Lundin... however.........

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no way you can write `memcpy` with the standard format and be fully MISRA compliant. As you seem to have noticed, MISRA doesn't allow `restrict`. But there's also the rule 11.5.

Rule 11.5 regarding casts from pointer-to-void to pointer-to-type is just too cumbersome to follow in practice. It is an Advisory rule so I would just skip it. You don't need to raise a deviation.

Rule 11.8 regarding casting away qualifiers is a sound one however (and Required). There is no reason why you should do this in this case. There is a bug in your code which was prevented by MISRA. Change the code to

```
const int_least8_t* source = (const int_least8_t*) src;
```

---

Additional notes:

- You need not provide a function declaration to `main()`.
- `stdio.h` is not allowed by MISRA-C.
- Avoid declaring identifiers starting with an underscore, see C11 7.1.3.
- There's no apparent benefit of using `int_least8_t` here. In addition, signed types are problematic. I would use `uint8_t` instead.

Comment: There's also a potential alignment issue with using `int_least8_t`. There's no guarantee the memory being copied is aligned to the type. I'd say use `unsigned char` because under any circumstances it could be different form `uin8_t` then `usigned char` would be the right answer.

Comment: @Persixty MISRA-C encourages the use of `stdint.h`, if you don't use the stdint types, you need a good reason. This is not a good reason - in case you have a system that doesn't support `uint8_t` but have 16 bit char, then you have some dysfunctional DSP. Which you should code in assembler and not in C. There is absolutely no need for the average C program to provide portability to oddball, exotic, obsolete DSPs. People who do that are simply wasting everyone's time. Providing portability to  real-world mainstream computer architectures is sufficient.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that. I agree it's wildly theoretical that somewhere in the motor industry someone uses something not 8-bit-byte (but I hereby don't put it past Renault or Fiat).
 
In the face of that (frankly draconian) rule I agree no good reason. 
But the alignment point remains. Casting `void *` to aligned types has another issue you didn't flag.

Comment: @Persixty Copying any `uint8_t` (or character type) to another variable of the same type is perfectly fine. Alignment issues arise when you try to access the pointed-at data as some other type, in which case you also get strict aliasing problems - and this isn't allowed by MISRA. Anyway, misalignment is no concern of "my_memcpy" in itself, but rather a concern from the caller. Apart from the fact that a copy based on aligned word size would have resulted in much faster code on some systems, rather than byte by byte.

Comment: (It might be a good idea to invent something like `void fastcpy (uint_fast8_t* dst, const uint_fast8_t* src, size_t size)` in addition to "my_memcpy".)

Comment: `uint8_t` will be fine. It's `int_least8_t` in the original code that's got a **theoretical** problem. If it were (unlikely) that wasn't an alias of `int8_t` then `destination[i] = source[i];` could in principle use aligned instructions and fail. Remember none of this is realistic on any modern platform because `int_least8_t` is going to be `int8_t` is going to be `signed char` is the unit of memory!

Comment: `uint_fast8_t` may well need to address alignment. `uint_fast8_t` is the fastest type with at least 8 bits. May be wider and aligned on a optimized platform. It's most likely to use aligned instructions - on account of being advertised as fast! You can write `my_memcpy()` to do first odd bytes as `uint8_t`, the body as a wider type and last bytes as `uint8_t`.

Comment: @Lundin If I don't forward declare main I get a MISRA error 8.4: `[MISRAC2012-Rule-8.4]:Definition of externally-linked...` perhaps it is a bug in IAR C-STAT...

Comment: @nowox - you need to raise that with IAR... main() does not require a prototype :-)